# Magento 2.3 prefix radio button

Tags: magento2, checkout, prefix

I want to change the default prefix select box to a radio select box.
Therefore I added the following module, but it is not changing the select to radio.

What am I missing here?

/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="sr_ModuleName_checkout_layout_processor" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Block/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'])) {

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['prefix']['component'] = "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/checkbox-set";

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['prefix']['config']['elementTmpl'] = "ui/form/element/checkbox-set";

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['prefix']['config']['multiple'] = false;
        }

        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list'])) {
            $paymentsList = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];

            foreach ($paymentsList as $paymentCode => $payment) {
                if(strpos($paymentCode, '-form') === false) {
                    continue;
                }
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentCode]['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['component'] = "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/checkbox-set";
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentCode]['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['config']['elementTmpl'] = "ui/form/element/checkbox-set";
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentCode]['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['config']['multiple'] = false;
            }
        }
        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['component'] = "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/checkbox-set";

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['config']['elementTmpl'] = "ui/form/element/checkbox-set";

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['config']['multiple'] = false;
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Duplicate question. Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227177/magento2-change-customer-name-prefix-to-radio-button-from-dropdown-on-checkout

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: @SohelRana Magento 2.3.0. Saw that question and tried that, but for some reason it does not change the select box.

Answer (score 1):

Options are missing. Try the following code:

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Block;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'])) {

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['prefix']['component'] = "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/checkbox-set";
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['prefix']['options'] = $this->getOptions();

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['prefix']['config']['elementTmpl'] = "ui/form/element/checkbox-set";

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['prefix']['config']['multiple'] = false;
        }

        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list'])) {
            $paymentsList = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];

            foreach ($paymentsList as $paymentCode => $payment) {
                if(strpos($paymentCode, '-form') === false) {
                    continue;
                }
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentCode]['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['component'] = "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/checkbox-set";
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentCode]['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['options'] = $this->getOptions();
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentCode]['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['config']['elementTmpl'] = "ui/form/element/checkbox-set";
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentCode]['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['config']['multiple'] = false;
            }
        }
        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['component'] = "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/checkbox-set";

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['options'] = $this->getOptions();

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['config']['elementTmpl'] = "ui/form/element/checkbox-set";

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['prefix']['config']['multiple'] = false;
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

    private function getOptions()
    {
        return [
            [
                'value' => 'Mr.',
                'label' => 'Mr.'
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'Mrs.',
                'label' => 'Mrs.'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But still the same, the prefix is still displayed as a select box instead of the radio buttons.

Comment: I have checked fresh installed m2.3. Working fine. Not sure your case. Check carefully if another plugin overwrite this or not. Here you assign radio button component so something wrong in your end

Comment: That's quite strange. I also tried it on a fresh install of 2.3, but it still shows the prefix as a select box instead of radiobuttons. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you create new module for this? If not then create new module and add answer with your module

Comment: Also debug, plugin called or not, for this add some debug log

Comment: Yes I created a module for this, just like the path above, that should be enough to load the module, right? It looks like the files are not loaded on the checkout page. I just changed the block name to `namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block1;` but that does not break down the page. So it seems that the module is not loaded.

Comment: Solved, forgot a custom file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe a last question that you do know, is there a way to select the first value by default, as checked?

Comment: Any idea how to check the first value by default?