# Magento2 : Change Customer name Prefix to Radio button from Dropdown on Checkout page, cant be at the Osc for mageplaza billing address

Tags: magento2, prefix, mageplaza, radio-fields

need to the Change Customer name Prefix to Radio button from Dropdown on the checkout page
I followed this solution 
[Magento2 : Change Customer name Prefix to Radio button from Dropdown on Checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227177/magento2-change-customer-name-prefix-to-radio-button-from-dropdown-on-checkout)

and it solved the shipping address but the billing address at the Mageplaza_Osc cant be change to the radio

can anyone help me with this
thanks